# Django/Celery multiple queues on localhost - routing not working

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I followed celery [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing) to define 2 queues on my dev machine.

My celery settings:

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60  # 1 mins
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 4
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('feeds', Exchange('feeds'), routing_key='arena.social.tasks.#'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'arena.social.tasks.Update': {
        'queue': 'fs_feeds',
    },
}
```

i opened two terminal windows, in virtualenv of my project, and ran following commands:

```
terminal_1$ celery -A arena worker -Q default -B -l debug --purge -n deafult_worker
terminal_2$ celery -A arena worker -Q feeds -B -l debug --purge -n feeds_worker
```

what i get is that all tasks are being processed by both queues.

My goal is to have one queue to process only the one task defined in `CELERY_ROUTES` and default queue to process all other tasks.

I also followed this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079816/route-celery-task-to-specific-queue), `rabbitmqctl list_queues` returns `celery 0`, and running `rabbitmqctl list_bindings` returns `exchange  celery  queue   celery  []` twice. Restarting rabbit server didn't change anything.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out. Following is my whole setup, settings and how to run celery, for those who might be wondering about same thing as my question did.

**Settings**

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 4
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1

# celery queues setup
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('feeds', Exchange('feeds'), routing_key='long_tasks'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'arena.social.tasks.Update': {
        'queue': 'feeds',
        'routing_key': 'long_tasks',
    },
}
```

**How to run celery?**

*terminal - tab 1:*

```
celery -A proj worker -Q default -l debug -n default_worker
```

this  will start first worker that consumes tasks from default queue. NOTE! `-n default_worker` is not a must for the first worker, but is a must if you have any other celery instances up and running. Setting `-n worker_name` is the same as `--hostname=default@%h`.

*terminal - tab 2:*

```
celery -A proj worker -Q feeds -l debug -n feeds_worker
```

this will start second worker that consumers tasks from feeds queue. Notice `-n feeds_worker`, if you are running with `-l debug` (log level = debug), you will see that both workers are syncing between them.

*terminal - tab 3:*

```
celery -A proj beat -l debug
```

this will start the beat, executing tasks according to the schedule in your `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`.
I didn't have to change the task, or the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`.

For example, this is how looks my `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` for the task that should go to feeds queue:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    ...
    'update_feeds': {
        'task': 'arena.social.tasks.Update',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/6'),
    },
    ...
}
```

As you can see, no need for adding `'options': {'routing_key': 'long_tasks'}` or specifying to what queue it should go. Also, if you were wondering why `Update` is upper cased, its because its a custom task, which are defined as sub classes of `celery.Task`.

**Update Celery 5.0+**

Celery made a couple changes since version 5, here is an updated setup for routing of tasks.

**How to create the queues?**

Celery can create the queues automatically. It works perfectly for simple cases, where celery default values for routing are ok.

`task_create_missing_queues=True` or, if you're using django settings and you're namespacing all celery configs under `CELERY_` key, `CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES=True`. Note, that it is on by default.

**Automatic scheduled task routing**

After configuring celery app:

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
  "some_scheduled_task": {
    "task": "module.path.some_task",
    "schedule": crontab(minute="*/10"),
    "options": {"queue": "queue1"}
  }
}
```

**Automatic task routing**

Celery app still has to be configured first and then:

```
app.conf.task_routes = {
  "module.path.task2": {"queue": "queue2"},
}
```

**Manual routing of tasks**

In case and you want to route the tasks dynamically, then when sending the task specify the queue:

```
from module import task

def do_work():
  # do some work and launch the task
  task.apply_async(args=(arg1, arg2), queue="queue3")
```

More details re routing can be found here:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html

And regarding calling tasks here:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html

Comment: I was using new format 'task_queue' on celery 3.1. Using 'CELERY_ROUTES' is working.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to accepted answer, if anyone comes here and still wonders why his settings aren't working (as I did just moments ago), here's why: celery documentation isn't listing settings names properly.

For celery 5.0.5 settings `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE`, `CELERY_QUEUES`, `CELERY_ROUTES` should be named `CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE`, `CELERY_TASK_QUEUES`and `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES` instead. These are settings that I've tested, but my guess is the same rule applies for exchange and routing key aswell.